# How can i remove all the forward slash "/", Colons ":" and spaces from DateTime.Now format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to convert DataTime.Now output into a interger,

I want to remove all the forward slash "/" Colons ":" and spaces " " even PM/AM.

example:

From = 1/24/2022 10:51:54 PM

to = 1242022105154

Comment: Note that you want the 64-bit `long` integer variant 32-bit `int` variant (as that tops out at 2147483647 when signed).

Comment: Also, how do you intend to signify AM or PM with this format?

Comment: I'm also wondering how you distinguish 4th December from 24th January with this format.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm hoping that OP would expect 1204 and 124, and then start from the right-hand side to convert this back to its individual components. Otherwise.... things could go badly.

Comment: Tip: when you format as year-month-day (etc), then the result sorts correctly in date order. As opposed to putting day or month first

Comment: OP: Why have you changed your username from Dushyant Singh to Jeet? Is it because you're also [this Dushyant Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845402/3181933)?

Comment: If you want to convert this to a `long` for storage (serialisation) purposes rather than needing a specific format, you could consider just using `DateTime.Ticks`.

Comment: @llama most bizarre behavior; using a sock account to post a terrible answer to a terrible question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this :

```
long n = long.Parse(date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

if you want in string format :

```
var n = date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

And you can change the location of the year and month in the above field. for example :(this is correct for your question)

```
var n = date.ToString("MddyyyyHHmmss");
```

where date is your variable contain date value.

Comment: Not strictly speaking necessary to convert to long but might make parsing the value back to DateTime easier that way. I'd have just done the `.ToString()` with the output format I wanted

Comment: I change my answer.

Comment: You don't have to trip via string by the way; c#'s pretty good at multiplying numbers!

Answer (score -2):

You can use as below:

```
From.ToString().Replace("/","").Replace(":","").Replace(" ","")
```

Comment: What if `.ToString()` doesn't yield a date in the format OP desires?

Comment: There are built in .Net extensions that would assist in formatting things the way you need to. While .Replace takes care of the literal request, there are certainly better ways to handle this such as specifying the specific format as others have suggested.